# How to repeat a command forever in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm running a command that I want to rerun when it completes, without needing to navigate back to the terminal to enter the command again.

I know in Ubuntu, I can run a terminal with a command, and it'll loop forever if I have it set up right, something like `gnome-terminal -x $MY_COMMAND`.

Given that I can't mark Powershell to rerun the command instead of closing the window, how can I repeat a command indefinitely?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out the answer is fairly straight forward, wrap the command in a loop forever. This'll allow you to Ctrl-C out of it, and it'll keep repeating even after your command completes or otherwise exits the first time.

```
while ($true) {
  my_command;
}
```

Or in my case as a one liner: `while ($true) { python3 .\manage.py runserver_plus 8080; }`

Comment: You should use the invoke operator with external commands.  `& python3 --% C:\path\manage.py runserver_plus 8080`.  Your semicolon is unnecessary.

Comment: That doesn't solve the failing problem, a syntax error still kills the process or whatever, and I need to repeat the command again.

Comment: Your question and answer don't make any sense.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: There are only 2 reasons for needing `&` to invoke a command, whether external or not: (a) if the command's name requires _quoting_, e.g. because it has embedded whitespace, or (b) if its name is stored in a _variable_. With literal `python3`, `&` is _not_ required. Using `--%` without explaining why is ill-advised.

Comment: @mklement0 using `--%` is a good practice in any situation you're calling an external program so there are no errors in argument parsing.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible: `--%`, the [stop-parsing symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing) completely changes the semantics of argument parsing - which may or may not be the right tool, depending on the circumstances.
In fact, I'd stay away from it, unless you have a preexisting command line used with `cmd.exe` that you don't really understand but want to reuse as-is.
It certainly is _not_ needed here, and casually throwing it in without explaining its implications can cause confusion in the future.

Answer (score 6):

This will infinitely run a command repeatedly after execution completes:

```
while ($true) {
    Start-Process -FilePath python3 -ArgumentList .\manage.py, runserver_plus, 8080 -Wait -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

Alternatively:

```
#requires -Version 3

while ($true) {
    try {
        $params = @{FilePath     = 'python3'
                    ArgumentList = '.\manage.py', 'runserver_plus', '8080'
                    Wait         = $true
                    ErrorAction  = 'Stop'}
        Start-Process @params
    } catch {
        <# Deal with errors #>
        continue
    }
}
```

Comment: best if the error handler if the "forever" is important.

Comment: I mean it's best to choose the variant with internal try/catch that guarantees that the loop never stops, this fulfilling the forever premise.

Comment: (a) Don't use `Start-Process` to run console applications; (b) your command opens a new window, which you should at least mention; (c) `try` / `catch` is pointless here, because an external utility will never cause an error (except if it cannot be invoked at all, in which case you'll get into a tight error loop), so `-ErrorAction ...` has no effect. Asides: (d) don't use `@(...)` for array literals, it is unnecessary (and inefficient in PSv5 and below); (e) it's better to explain why `1` also works as a Boolean in PowerShell, given that `$True` is the direct way of expressing one.

Comment: @mklement0 (a) `Start-Process` can be used to run any application.  (b) `NoNewWindow=$True` voila.  (c) External utilities absolutely CAN throw terminating errors. (d) do you have any proof it's any less efficient? (e) common sense

Comment: Re (a) Yes, but there's no good reason to run a _console_ application that way, unless you want a separate window (which the OP doesn't); to run a console application _synchronously_, just invoke it directly (which also keeps it connected to the standard streams).
So, re (b), use of `-NoNewWindow`, is therefore a moot point, but if you do want to stick with `Start-Process`, at least include it in your answer.

Comment: Re (c): Other than PowerShell not _finding_ an external executable (in which case it is not _the external utility_ that's causing the error), external utilities (console applications) don't cause errors  - except due to a _bug_, described [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4002), and in the _ISE_.
Re (d): `@(...)` being _mistaken_ for array-literal syntax is reason enough not to use it; the efficiency issue is a secondary point, but you can read about it [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4280).

Comment: Re (e) It is best to avoid (unexplained) shortcuts in SO answers lest beginners get confused.